# EF7 Not Mapping Objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I building a set of simple models which are mapped to an existing database through EF7.

Here's an example of the two models:

```
public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I attempt to retrieve the models from the database (such as get a specific Book), all the data comes back properly except "Person" remains null and I can't seem to get that data back no matter what. I checked the database, and there is a foreign key relation between the two tables.

I am using this method to retrieve my objects.

```
public async Task<T> FindAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match)
            where T : class
        {
            return await context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(match);
        }
```

What is interesting is when I create a migration and use it to create my own test database (using LocalDB), everything appears to work fine which I find very strange.

Does anybody have any insight as to why my objects are not populating?

Comment: Have you tried load your query as eager loading?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi I have done both ways, and neither has worked.

Comment: Did you checked if the migration correctly applied to database, I mean the if `PersonId` is foreign key in `Books` table?

Comment: In my test case, the migration does apply correctly. However, for production, I am going against an existing database - so no migrations. I did check to ensure a foreign key is set up properly and everything appeared in order.

Comment: Have you tried to include the person? `return await context.Books.Include(i => i.Person).SingleOrDefaultAsync(match);` try this just for test purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
return await context.Books.Include(b => b.Person).SingleOrDefaultAsync(match); // book.Person will be loaded
```

**Update:**

> Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity
>   also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is
>   achieved by use of the Include method. [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#eager)

Comment: This does work (although, creates some issues with JSON serialization). What I'm not understanding, however, is why this has to be done at all? I've never had to use Include for anything prior to EF7. Can you provide any clarity into that?

Comment: @JasCav Check the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, this doesn't really help. I have successfully used - Lazy Loading + Serialization in the past. I'm guessing there's some (major?) change with EF7 that's causing me these issues, because this is the first time I've seen this problem and have been using EF for quite some time.

Comment: EF7 does not lazy load currently you Have to use e.g. Include(c=>c.Wheels).ThenInclude(w=>w.LugNuts) etc

Comment: @JasCav If it's not clear from the comments above, Entity Framework 7 [does not support lazy loading](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3312). There is debate within the EF7 team as to whether it ever will.

Comment: @Matt Thank you. Yes, I discovered the appropriate GitHub threads where I am tracking the external conversation. I understand the trade-off and it's not such a big deal for first time. It was the transition from EF6 to EF7 that was jarring.